# How to convert strings to SEPA format?

Tags: c#

I need to convert strings to SEPA format.

I am integrating my app with a 3rd party tool that requires SEPA formated strings.
https://www.europeanpaymentscouncil.eu/sites/default/files/KB/files/EPC217-08-SEPA-Conversion-Table.xls

For example if I have customer name 
"O’CONNOR" (HTML: & rsquo;) I should convert it to "O'CONNOR" before sending to the 3rd party tool.
If I don't do this I get error

```
...some characters are not part of SEPA.
```

I am writing this value to a cell in .XLSX file which I generate using OfficeOpenXml library. Then uploading the .XLSX file to 3rd party provider website.

Is there any easy way to implement this in C#, or must I implement custom method that goes 1 by 1 through all the cases mentioned in the link above and try to replace the characters in the string?

Comment: Does this Apach-2.0-licensed project help you? https://github.com/perrich/sepawriter

Comment: @knittl no this does not seem to help. I am able to create this object and no validations and transformations are performed.
            var transfer = new SepaCreditTransfer
            {
                MessageIdentification = "msg`",
                InitiatingPartyName = "O’CONNOR-Š α",
                // Below, your bank data
                Debtor = new SepaIbanData { Bic = "SOGEFRPPXXX", Iban = "FR7030002005500000157845Z02", Name = "My Corp" }
            };
I just see exactly the same string in the object.